# Run different java based on command line parameter

Tags: command-line, java, versions, update-alternatives

I have multiple java installations on my machine and need to use different versions all the time. I have found that the currently used JVM can be changed by the commands `update-alternatives` and `update-java-alternatives`, which essentially change the link at `/etc/alternatives/java` etc. to point to the correct JVM installation.

Is it possible to run different versions of java by specifying a command line parameter? E.g., to run maven for example in the following ways:

```
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/ mvn clean install

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/ mvn clean install
```

*EDIT: Above commands work*

We can verify that the above commands work by running

```
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_32, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.32/jre
```

The java version and home are correct in the example.

*EDIT: Solution to the problem*

The original problem was caused by an interface named `CommonDataSource` changed in the jre's `rt.jar`, which caused incompatibility between different JREs. The solution was to add the java 6's `rt.jar` to the classpath:

```
JAVA_HOME=$JAVA6_HOME MAVEN_OPTS="-Xbootclasspath/a:$JAVA6_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar" mvn clean install
```

Comment: Don't the examples you show do precisely what you want? Java based software will normally honour the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why the compiling process does not take the `JAVA_HOME` variable in account while determining the compilation classpath. In this case the `rt.jar` did come from the JDK7 even if the `JAVA_HOME` was set. Similarly, the `-Xbootclasspath` option did not work by itself. Instead, setting `JAVA_HOME` to point to jdk6 was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you show do precisely what you are looking for. So, though a command line parameter will not do the trick, an environment variable will. And you can specify 'one-time' environment variables on the command-line, preceding the command.

Most, if not all, Java based software will honour the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and run the JVM located underneath that directory.  Maven certainly does: have a look at `less $(which mvn)` and see just how much effort it puts in getting this right.

Note that - in the specific case of Maven - if your goal is to compile Java sources for an older JVM version, then there is no need to switch JVMs. Instead, specify the source and target Java versions in your POM.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. The project's `source` and `target` are both set to `1.6`, but still it shows compilation error on my JDK7. This is because Java 7 has an added method `CommonDataSource#getParentLogger()`. The build runs fine if I first run `update-java-alternatives --set java-6-sun` and then `mvn install`, but not with `update-java-alternatives --set java-7-oracle`. Not with normal `mvn install` nor `JAVA_HOME=... mvn install`. Need to further investigate this..

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to fix the source code so it is forward compatible? I.e. implement `getParentLogger()` on whichever class implements the `CommonDataSource` interface? BTW: are you sure the source and target versions are picked up in the compile phase?

Comment: The problem was resolved by adding `-Xbootclasspath/a:$JAVA6_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar` to `MAVEN_OPTS` when compiling it while simultaneously using the `source` and `target?  parameters of the `maven-compiler-plugin`. The dependency comes straight from the JRE's own `rt.jar`

Comment: For the source to be compatible with java versions 6 and 7, I would need to add the method without the `@Override` annotation since it would then break with anyone compiling it with jdk 6.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer to the question. However, it seems that my problem was different. Thank you in any case!